# Can i have the treegrid structure in my hierarchical treestructure in the same nattable? Can i combine both?

Tags: nattable, nebula, hierarchical-trees

I want to have the treegrid strcuture(screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ox9J.jpg) where we have the root object at the top and then A and A.1 and so on get expanded as comparator handles that, but i want to know how to have this functionality in the hierarchical grid table,its a tricky think to ask, but i need to know what things i need to change and what should be my approach towards getting that functionality, how the bodylayerstack should look like and i want to keep the hierarchy and i want to add the tree format in the hierarchical table at least in the first column.
Your answer will be highly apprecaited. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a tree or a hierachical tree representation. It is not supported to combine those two representations. You can not re-use the TreeFormat from the tree representation as the hierarchical tree has its own internally. And if your data model is not a hierarchical data model, you can not use it in the hierachical representation. The hierarchical representation takes a hierachical data model and transfers it to a special wrapper model, where the tree takes a flat list and builds the tree structure from that. So you need to change your data model if you want to move to the hierarchical tree representation.